# How to add seconds to the time in a variable using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am generating a DataTimeStamp in UTC in sampler using below code
vars.put("DataTimeStamp", "${__groovy(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssssss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')),)}")

I need to add  30 seconds to time in variable "DataTimeStamp" in another sampler.

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Groovy's [TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) class like:

```
def now = new Date()
def nowFormatted = now.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssssss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
log.info(nowFormatted)

use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def nowPlus30Seconds = now + 30.seconds
    log.info(nowPlus30Seconds.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssssss"))
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: i see above code is not adding 30 seconds in output. intial time: 8:56:01 and after adding it is 9:56:31. i think its adding 1 hour 30 second. Sorry if i am missing anything..., can you please confirm the same.

Comment: Please ignore i fixed it using Format. thanks for your help. log.info("30 Current UTC Date" + nowPlus30Seconds.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssssss",TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')))